# Modify the predefined ontology by using jena

Tags: java, semantic-web, jena, ontology, owl

I created my ontology by Protege. my ontology has some classes and instances. Now i'm going to add other classes and instances by jena that's why i write the below code to create a new class and one instance  in this class. the name of new class is "person" and the name of new instance is "base". when i run this code in java it works without any error and create the class and instance. but when i back to protege i can not see the new class and also the new instance. do you have any idea to help me.
thanks

```
public void create_model(){                   
    modelMem = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM);
    ModelMaker modelMaker = ModelFactory.createFileModelMaker("Ontologies/VBnet.owl");
    Model modeltmp = modelMaker.createDefaultModel();
    modelMem = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM, modeltmp);
    System.out.println("Model has been Successfully Built");

}
public void addFile() {
    System.out.println("Loading from FOAF instance File");
    InputStream inFoafInstance =FileManager.get().open("Ontologies/VBnet.owl");
    modelMem.read(inFoafInstance, defaultNameSpace);
    //inFoafInstance.close();
    System.out.println(modelMem.toString());

}
public void adddata() {
   OntClass person = modelMem.createClass(defaultNameSpace + "Person");
   Individual l1 = modelMem.createIndividual( defaultNameSpace + "base", person );
   for (Iterator i = l1.listRDFTypes(true); i.hasNext(); )
       System.out.println( l1.getURI() + " is asserted in class " + i.next() );
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    AddInfo add=new AddInfo();
    add.create_model();
    add.addFile();
    add.adddata();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't seem to have saved the altered model:

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("altered.rdf");
modelMem.write( out, "RDF/XML-ABBREV"); // readable rdf/xml
out.close();
```